# Data structure for conditional probabilities with updating conditions

Tags: data-structures, probability, bayesian

I have a list of lists of 4 integers. All integers in the same list are distinct, e.g.,

```
data = [[8, 9, 3, 0], [3, 8, 4, 9], [7, 9, 6, 4], [3, 6, 4, 8], [0, 5, 3, 7], [0, 9, 4, 2], [9, 0, 1, 5], [3, 2, 8, 6], [3, 5, 4, 0], [1, 2, 5, 9], [1, 3, 6, 5], [2, 4, 5, 7], [7, 8, 6, 3], [6, 2, 9, 8], [8, 7, 5, 4], [8, 5, 1, 3]]
```

Currently I have a function that receives the list above and a list of distinct integers `certain`. The function returns a list with the probabilities of each integer (from 0 to 9) being in a list knowing that it contains the integers in `certain`.

```py
def probability(data, certain):
    probs = [0] * 10
    counter_total = 0
    set_certain = set(certain)
    for d in data:
        if set_certain.issubset(d):
            counter_total += 1
            for i in range(10):
                if i in d and i not in set_certain:
                    probs[i] += 1
    probs = [x / counter_total for x in probs]
    return probs
```

Initially, the list `certain` is empty and values are added later. Is there a data structure I can use in the start of the program so that I don't have to go through all the data again every time I append a new value to `certain`? The list `data` can be very big.